# Google Site: list template + local spreadsheet/database

Tags: download, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-sites, list-template

I am building a couple of "list" (based on the page template) pages on a google site. This is all great. The thing though is that I want to have a local copy (spreadsheet) as a backup or for offline use.

My first question is: can I somehow download the list as a spreadsheet?

Moreover, it would be much better if I could use the nice functionality of the list template (i.e; one simple form to enter all data for an entry; I already use this in my list template, including drop down lists, as well as the ability to sort by columns!) and at the same time be able to download a cope of the list or have it in my Drive.

Is that possible? and how?

thanks

Comment: With Google Apps Script you can do all without any dificulty and in a automated way. Did you try that? I suggest changing one of your tags (sorting) to [Google-apps-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) to get some opinions on that matter.

Comment: thanks for the reply;
Honestly I don't use the apps & I am not much of a programmer; I was looking for a simple solution.
In any case I'll check it out.

Comment: Ok if you need help you can find many answers here or in the g+ community.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can...sort off. It is possible to do some basic web scraping in Google Sheets with the functions:

[`IMPORTHTML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411&vid=1-635787171800270557-1611248032)

[`IMPORTXML`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)

Between the two, `IMPORTXML` works well to get specific data while `IMPORTHTML`  is perfect for grabbing tables [Using Google Sheets as a basic web scraper](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-sheet-web-scraper/).

From there you can download the Google Sheets with the list and keep a copy in your Google Drive normally an even export it as a PDF or excel file.